# Why all already set auto layout constrains are gone if change the frame of view?

Tags: iphone, ios6, autolayout

[image]

As shown in screen shot I made all 4 views' `widths equally` and `height equally` after that if i change the frame size of green view all the other constraints as `Horizontal spacing`,`vertical spacing` are gone and I have to start from the beginning for all view to work in both portrait and landscape.

Also after that i Set All constrains again and still in landscape mode labels are not showing properly as shown in screen shot[image]

I set these constrains.[image]

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Didn't get wat ur trying to achieve ??

Comment: I am just learning the new auto layout of ios6 with tutorial.But after setting all the constrains i changed the frame of one of the 4 views all constrains are gone i have to again implement them all

Comment: plz provide the link of the tutorial....

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2

Answer (score 1):

Look at the log for more information to make sure your constraints are breaking or not.

Follow these steps to see if you have **Unsatisfiable / Ambiguous Constraints**

1) Run the app and then pause it.

2) Type/send the following message to UIWindow in lldb debugger.

```
           po [UIWindow keyWindow] _autoLayoutTrace]
```

3) This gives you the auto-layout trace and you can easily figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: po [UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace] - lowercase 'l'

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the constraints which were already were removed is because the constraints were not satisfied. The system intelligently adjusts the constraints if it find the constraints were not satisfied. Refer to previous answer and make sure the autoLayoutTrace has no violations.